# Relay back emf cauisng my micro controller reset

Tags: transistors, diodes, relay, opto-isolator, flyback

I have a 5V 30A relay in my circuit. I made a PCB with all the connections to microcontroller and relay. At present I am using M7 smd diode as flyback diode. But problem is occuring if I switch on/off the relay fast. I tried some of the IN400 series but nothing takes me out of this problem. I don't know what the exact mistake is. Here is my circuit diagram:
[image]

Relay I am using — [5v 30A relay](https://ge.voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/power/JQX-15F(T90).pdf)

Optocoupler — EL817.
Please suggest me solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Much of what an optocoupler could offer is defeated when you use the same power supply on both sides.

Comment: Take ground and power leads from microcontroller and relay separately to the power supply. Have largish electrolytics capacitors at uC and relay. Place resistor in series with relay that drops say 0.5V to 1V at max relay holding current with large cap on relay side of resistor - so relay will hold on 4 to 4.5V BUT operate on 5V from cap. All this is aimed at separating uC and relay power feeds.

Comment: What load is the relay switching? Does it still reset the micro without the load? I'm thinking about EMI from sparks.

Comment: I think your problems source is voltage drop. Can you try add a 10uF or 100uF between 5V and GND lines? Also you can try that between EN pin of uC and GND.

Comment: Can you update your schematic to show any bypass capacitance (from power to ground) is used in this circuit? And how much at the microcontroller?  If the answer is "none" then there's your problem right away.

Comment: _"Here is my circuit diagram"_ this circuit appears to have been copied from [Electronics Hub](https://www.electronicshub.org/arduino-controlled-power-outlet/). What components are you using in it?

Comment: Have you tried schottky diode at D2?

Comment: What happens if the relay switch is disconnected at all 3 terminals  and so passes no current? Does the controller reset still occur?

Answer (score 1):

### This EMI problem is either conducted or radiated.

### Conducted

Shared supply lines with cascaded voltage drop rather than radial or star connected to a low impedance source .  Add low ESR caps near CPU or uC.

It may be caused by either DC voltage sag on Vcc or Vdd or + ground shift on 0V or Vss.

### Radiated

- This is more common and is a result of stray coupling from the antenna effects of a loop current rise time which is inverse to frequency

  - **ΔV=L ΔI/Δt ( or V=LdI/dt)**  and the mutual coupling of this current rise time in air at RF speeds.
- It may come from the coil current being switched from the transistor to the diode but is more likely the relay load being switched off with the inductive arc generated by the sudden break in current
- **there are many standard solutions to this problem.**
- first measure it, define the source of interference and offended input

  - distance ; keep the load wires far away if possible
  - orientation; do not put near in // near sensitive inputs, instead go at 90 deg. "right" angles
  - unshielded twisted pair cable (UTP) for both switch load and sensor cables
  - shielded twisted pair (STP) for both.
  - add an RC snubber across relay contacts (by design certain criteria)
  - add a ground plane to electronics or grounded enclosure , aka Faraday cage.
  - use a line filter between AC loads and protective earth ground (PE)
  - connect an RF Cap. between isolated supplies to shunt to common mode (CM) noise to protective earth (PE) ground,
  - add a Balun or CM choke  to  noisy motor line pairs (e.g large Ferrite torroid)
  - **add Ferrite beads and RF caps to uC input signals on cables and switched power**
  - use RF Cap feedthru connectors that shunt signal inputs with pF to case gnd or 0Vdc.
  - use Opto isolators between driver and switched load to reduce crosstalk { Opto-SCR, Opto-Relay, ZCS-opto-Triac driver} if truly isolated and not shared supplies
  - use Zero Crossing Sequence (ZCS) Triacs that drive capacitive or inductive loads
- ETC.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a conducted EMI problem, I would suggest three points:

1. put a RC snubber in parallel to the diode, because the diode voids overvoltages but does not avoid oscillations;
2. replace the jumper with  series inductor that decouples the rely from the +5V supply;
3. as already mentioned in the comments, include "capacitors between +5V and 0V.

Radiated coupling should be less likely, since the rest of the circuit is supposed to be compact. If you have log wires or loops, the you might have such problems (large loops should be corrected before thinking of additional patches and control measures). If the 0V is not terminated to ground you might have EMI problems as well, but again it is supposed that you have a correct termination to ground.